# Dependency injection in OWIN without using System.Web

Tags: owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am exploring on the use of Dependency injection in my OWIN project. I have gone through the code referred [here](https://github.com/DotNetDoodle/DotNetDoodle.Owin.Dependencies).

When I go through the code, I find dependency in the `System.Web.Http` dll. As far as I am concerned, we should be doing the dependency injection without the use of `System.Web` dlls, as OWIN does not depend on the heavy lifting by using `System.Web`.

Can anyone let me know if this can be achieved without using system.web. like having a middleware load the containers and then all the services being resolved via this container. If I can be given some expert opinion and explanation of how this can be achieved, I will be able to develop and share the code.

Comment: No comments or updates even from people from Microsoft, seems very disappointing